# Simplify the following algorithm

Tags: c#, linq, dictionary

I am using a LINQ query to retrieve a certain number of `KeyValuePair<string, string>` stored in a Dictionnary (named Prix which can contain 1 to n `KeyValuePair`). With the result of this query I fill a `DataRow` (in the switch).The maximum of prices stored in the `DataRow` is 3 except if `hasEAN` is true, in that case the maximum is 2. if I have only 1 price in Prix I store only 1 price. The algorythm is as follow :

```
List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> prices;
if (this.Prix.Count > 1)
{
    if (this.Prix.Count >= 2)
    {
        if (this.hasEAN)
        {
            prices = (from kvp in this.Prix
                      select kvp).Take(2).ToList();
        }
        else
        {
            prices = (from kvp in this.Prix
                      select kvp).Take(3).ToList();
        }
    }
    else
    {
        prices = (from kvp in this.Prix
                  select kvp).Take(1).ToList();
    }
}
else
{
    prices = null;
}

switch (prices.Count)
{
    case 1:
        res[8] = prices[0].Key;
        res[9] = prices[0].Value;
        break;
    case 2:
        res[8] = prices[0].Key;
        res[9] = prices[0].Value;
        res[10] = prices[1].Key;
        res[11] = prices[1].Value;
        break;
    case 3:
        res[8] = prices[0].Key;
        res[9] = prices[0].Value;
        res[10] = prices[1].Key;
        res[11] = prices[1].Value;
        res[12] = prices[2].Key;
        res[13] = prices[2].Value;
        break;
    default:
        break;
}
```

I feel like it could be much simpler but im not familiar with LINQ queries.

Comment: You can simplify your switch-case to this: `for(int i = 0; i < prices.Count; i++){res[8+i] = prices[i].Key;res[9+i] = prices[i].Value;}`

Comment: Working code in [codereview please](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/?as=1)

Comment: if (this.Prix.Count > 1) and if (this.Prix.Count >= 2) are the same test. I think you only need three cases for this.Prix.Count: 0, 1, >1 which you could do with an if/if else/else block.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel Thanks, I am not familiar with all stackexchange network. Ill post there in the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At least the first part of your code can be shortened:

```
List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> prices = null;
if (Prix.Any())
{
    int count = Prix.Count == 1 ? 1 : hasEAN ? 2 : 3;
    prices = Prix.Take(count).ToList();
}
```

Comment: I **always** forgot about the conditionnal operator. I'm fairly new in programming and I tend too often to abuse if statement. Thanks a lot this is really much simpler to read and write.

Answer (score 1):

```
List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> prices = this.Prix.Count <= 1 ? null : (from kvp in this.Prix select kvp).Take(this.Prix.Count < 2 ? 1 : this.hasEAN ? 2 : 3).ToList();

switch (prices.Count)
{
    case 3:
        res[12] = prices[2].Key;
        res[13] = prices[2].Value;
            goto case 2;
    case 2:
        res[10] = prices[1].Key;
        res[11] = prices[1].Value;
            goto case 1;
    case 1:
        res[8] = prices[0].Key;
        res[9] = prices[0].Value;
        break;
    default:
        break;
}
```

Comment: C# doesn't allow case statements to fall through, `break` (or similar) is mandatory.

Comment: And I had no idea about the `goto case` statement! Thanks for that.

Answer (score 1):

This is certainly possible in one line with Linq as you can see from other answers but spare a thought for future maintainability, what will you do in future if your rules change to introduce more complexity? 
You *can* simplify to only define the query once:

```
List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> prices;
//we'll always want at least one
int numberToTake=1;
//if we have more than one price though
if (this.Prix.Count>1)
{
  //check if we have more than 2
   if (this.Prix.Count >= 2)
   {
   //and if we have an EAN, take only 2 prices
    if (this.hasEAN)
    {
        numberToTake=2;
    }
    else
    {
     //if no EAN, take 3 prices.
      numberToTake=3;
    }
  }
}
prices = (from kvp in this.Prix select kvp).Take(numberToTake).ToList();
switch (prices.Count)
{
 //...your switch here.
}
```

and for best results, roll this into a function in your business rules for the object (whatever `this` is) that returns `numberToTake`, but if you only want to do compress to a single-liner just because it looks better, I would urge you to reconsider.

Comment: My business rule is not likely to ever change. Ill keep your advice in mind if I ever have to change it. Thanks :)